# Wrapping text in a cell adds a second checkbox in nearby cell

Tags: excel

I have 2 tables. One that works perfectly well regarding my question. here is an example:

[image]

As you can see, when theres more than one line, it wraps in the cell, and to it's left, nothing happen to the checkboxes.

But in the second table, that is just below the first one, when the cell wraps up my text, it adds another checkbox the the nearby cells.

[image]

What is the problem? How to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing added. After row height changed, the checkbox controls of row below are within the row which is higher now. Controls are not **in** cells but hover over the cells in a separate drawing layer. So either the checkboxes in second table are placed too near by the top edge of the rows or they are set to be independent of cell positions.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for your comment, and sorry for my late reply.   I'm not sure I understood your comment. Every checkbox is individually linked to it's own cell...